# error with "ON DELETE SET NULL" mysql mamp

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, foreign-key-relationship, ddl

i'm trying to add a "ON DELETE SET NULL" on my sql script, but it doesn't work...
Here is my table:

[image]

Serie table is for description of the serie and type table is for the type of this series (drama, comedy, etc.)
The sql script is:

```
    #------------------------------------------------------------
    #        Script MySQL.
    #------------------------------------------------------------


    #------------------------------------------------------------
    # Table: serie
    #------------------------------------------------------------

    CREATE TABLE serie(
            id_serie            Int NOT NULL ,
            original_name_serie Varchar (256) ,
            french_name_serie   Varchar (256) ,
            creation_date_serie Int ,
            end_date_serie      Int ,
            status_serie        Varchar (256) ,
            duration_serie      Int ,
            synopsis_serie      Varchar (2024) ,
            countries_serie     Varchar (128) ,
            PRIMARY KEY (id_serie )
    )ENGINE=InnoDB;


    #------------------------------------------------------------
    # Table: type
    #------------------------------------------------------------

    CREATE TABLE type(
            id_type   Int NOT NULL ,
            name_type Varchar (128) ,
            PRIMARY KEY (id_type )
    )ENGINE=InnoDB;


    #------------------------------------------------------------
    # Table: have
    #------------------------------------------------------------

    CREATE TABLE have(
            id_type  Int ,
            id_serie Int NOT NULL ,
            PRIMARY KEY (id_type ,id_serie )
    )ENGINE=InnoDB;

    ALTER TABLE have ADD CONSTRAINT FK_have_id_type FOREIGN KEY (id_type) REFERENCES type(id_type) ON DELETE SET NULL;
    ALTER TABLE have ADD CONSTRAINT FK_have_id_serie FOREIGN KEY (id_serie) REFERENCES serie(id_serie) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

With this script, I want when I delete a 'type' in the type table, the value of 'type' in 'have' table passed to 'null', this is why I add "ON DELETE SET NULL".
But it doesn't work, I have:  "#1005 - Can't create table 'zz.#sql-16527_272' (errno: 150) (Détails…) "

I think it's maybe i tried to put a null value in a primary key in the 'have' table and it's not possible... But who can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

The `id_type` column in the `type` table is the table's primary key, and thus cannot be set to `null`.

One way to solve this could be to change the logic of the foreign key (e.g., use `on delete cascade`, or just allow deletions to fail if the referenced row still exists).

Another option would be to remove the primary key from the `type` table and instead just have a `unique` key on that column, thus allowing `null`s. You'd also have to remove the explicit `not null`constraint on this column.

Comment: Thanks ! I remove the primary key in 'have' and replace with unique, it works :).

Answer (score 2):

The column type is defined to be NOT NULL, therefore you cannot insert NULL. Remove this from the definition and it should work.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work because 'id_type' into 'have' was the primary key and you can't put null value in a primary key.
Thanks anyway, i changed the primary key with a unique constraint and it works :)